# Can you use scoped filter with batch consumer in MassTransit?

Tags: c#, .net-core, masstransit

I tried to use scoped filter with a batch consumer but got an exception on start up. I tested the batch consumer and filter in isolation and they work fine.

Main method:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new HostBuilder()
        .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
        .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>((hostBuilderContext, builder) =>
        {                    
            // scoped filter
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MyFilter<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();                    

            builder.AddMassTransit(configurator =>
            {                                                
                configurator.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Durable = true;
                    cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), h =>
                    {
                        h.Username("guest");
                        h.Password("guest");
                    });
                    
                    cfg.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(MyFilter<>), context);                            
                    
                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("hello-queue", endpointConfigurator =>
                    {                      
                        endpointConfigurator.Batch<SayHello>(b =>
                        {
                            b.MessageLimit = 100;
                            b.ConcurrencyLimit = 10;
                            b.TimeLimit = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                            b.Consumer(() => new BatchConsumer());                                    
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {                    
            services.AddHostedService<HostedService>();
        });

    await host.Build().RunAsync();
}
```

The exception:

Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: 'An exception was thrown while activating λ:Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService[] -> CommandProcessor.HostedService -> λ:MassTransit.IBusControl -> λ:MassTransit.Registration.IBusInstance.'

Stack trace:

```
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.CreateInstance(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ResolveComponent(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(ResolveRequest request)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType)
   at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.<StartAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.<RunAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at CommandProcessor.Program.<Main>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up your code to use the proper batch configuration, resolving the consumer from the container, and configuring the receive endpoint properly.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new HostBuilder()
        .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
        .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>((hostBuilderContext, builder) =>
        {
            // scoped filter
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MyFilter<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            
            builder.AddMassTransit(configurator =>
            {
                configurator.AddConsumer<BatchConsumer, BatchConsumerDefinition>();

                configurator.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), h =>
                    {
                        h.Username("guest");
                        h.Password("guest");
                    });

                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("hello-queue", endpointConfigurator =>
                    {
                        endpointConfigurator.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(MyFilter<>), context);

                        endpointConfigurator.ConfigureConsumer<BatchConsumer>(context);
                    });
                });
            });
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<HostedService>();
        });

    await host.Build().RunAsync();
}

class BatchConsumerDefinition :
    ConsumerDefinition<BatchConsumer>
{
    protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator,
            IConsumerConfigurator<BatchConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
    {
        consumerConfigurator.Options<BatchOptions>(options => options
            .SetMessageLimit(100)
            .SetTimeLimit(1000)
            .SetConcurrencyLimit(10));
    }
}
```

As far as I know, scoped filters should work. The challenge is, you want the scope per-message, or per-batch, and that might require moving it to the consumer configurator for the `Batch<T>` directly.

Also, the consumer definition is used to specify the batch options (you were using the legacy syntax, which isn't recommended).

Comment: I was on 7.0.6, updated to 7.0.7 and now it works, Thanks! It appears that the scope is per batch, which is what I want.